# Single quotes inside single quotes cause error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<span onmouseout="tooltip.hide();" onmouseover="tooltip.show('Hello. This is a simple tooltip, I'm here if you need me, we've been away for some time.');" class="hotspot">test link</span>
```

the thing is that the SINGLE quote `'` is causing the tooltip not to show... so I mean IF the text contains `'` the tooltip will not show... because all the text is already inside single quotes...

Can someone please help me to fix this?

Comment: It's a quote, and you can escape it with `\'`, so it becomes `I\'m` instead.

Comment: the thing is that the content inside "tooltip.show" id DYNAMIC, so it's the USER that is entering the text there..

Comment: You probably actually need to fix this server-side. Based on a comment below, I guess you're using Joomla? You should update your question (and tags) to reflect this if so, as it will hopefully attract the right sort of attention

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the tooltip text to a var and then doing a replace on the single quote with `&apos;`

```
var tooltip = tooltip.replace(/'/g, "&apos;");
```

Comment: this is the actual text variable that I have now:

`$numwords = 50;`

`preg_match("/(\S+\s*){0,$numwords}/", $this->row->description, $regs);`

`$desc = str_replace('"', "", preg_replace('/(\s\s+|\t|\n)/', ' ', JFilterOutput::cleanText($regs[0])));`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this myself.

So I just replaced every instance of ' to \' in str_replace function :)

WAS:

```
$desc = str_replace('"', "",  preg_replace('/(\s\s+|\t|\n)/', ' ', JFilterOutput::cleanText($regs[0])));
```

IS NOW:

```
$desc = str_replace("'", "\\'",  preg_replace('/(\s\s+|\t|\n)/', ' ', JFilterOutput::cleanText($regs[0])));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `&rsquo;` for Special Characters in HTML.

```
<span onmouseout="tooltip.hide();" onmouseover="tooltip.show('Hello. This is a simple tooltip, I&rsquo;m here if you need me, we&rsquo;ve been away for some time.');" class="hotspot">test link</span>
```

> I created Working Demo with `alert()` you can run this code snippet :)

```html
<span onmouseover="alert('Hello. This is a simple tooltip, I&rsquo;m here if you need me, we&rsquo;ve been away for some time.');"
class="hotspot">test link</span>
```